# unable to load your rules realtime

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I can't open the realtime database on firebase. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Hey Mhamad. We're seeing some reports of the Firebase Realtime Database console being inaccessible in certain locations where it worked before. 1) Can you tell me from what location you're trying to access the console from? 2) Can you try of the problem disappears if you access the same page over a VPN connection?

Comment: Hello, I'm from Lebanon and when i use vpn it's working well

Comment: Thanks for confirming. We're seeing multiple reports from developers in Lebanon that are unable to access the Firebase console for their Realtime Database. I recommend reaching out to your ISP.